# Error : DEP6100 : Downloading package '7123B57E-F819-4B1E-8EE2-677E10756394'

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, virtual-machine, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm trying to deploy my first WP app from Visual Studio 2013. But when I run teh app on Device, I got the error:

> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during
>   boostrapping stage 'Downloading package
>   '7123B57E-F819-4B1E-8EE2-677E10756394'':  FileNotFoundException - The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    FilePicker.WindowsPhone

I'm working on Vmware.

Answer (score 0):

Some users have this problem, but no real solution.
I find a way to solve it
I think it`s a language problem
you can change your language at tools -options-international settings
then Restart vs.
example my default language is chinese I change it to english
the problem was sloved.